# How do I access environment variables in package.json in Vite?

Tags: reactjs, npm, environment-variables, vite

I am trying to run this npm script which waits for a response from the url specified in `env`:

concurrently "cd .. && cd backend && npm run dev" "wait-on -v $API_URL && vite"

Let me know if you think there is more straight-forward solution to "waiting on" an `env` specified url

I have tried a few different solutions most involving making vite compatible with `dotenv`. I don't know if this is the right solution and am not sure if there will be issues with prod vs dev builds. With the following setup, I get an error, thrown from the npm script in question:

`ValidationError: "resources[0]" is not allowed to be empty`

Here are my files after following [this article](https://dev.to/whchi/how-to-use-processenv-in-vite-ho9):

vite.config.ts:

```js
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'
const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '');

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  return {
    plugins: [react()],
    test: {
      environment: "jsdom",
      setupFiles: "./tests/setup.ts"
    },
    define: {
      'process.env.API_URL': JSON.stringify(env.API_URL || 'http://localhost:3000'),
    },
  };
})
```

npm script:

`concurrently \"cd .. && cd backend && npm run dev\" \"cross-env API_URL=$API_URL wait-on -v $API_URL && vite\"`

Answer (score 0):

In order to get access to data in your **.env** file in your React+Vite aplication you need to use `import.meta.env.VITE_YOUR_VARIABLE`.

To prevent accidentally leaking env variables to the client, only variables prefixed with **VITE_** are exposed to your Vite-processed code.

How to example:

1. Create .env file.
2. Add `VITE_SOME_KEY=123` to .env.
3. In your component `console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_KEY) // "123"`

**Note** that without **VITE_** prefix it will not work.

For additional information see [vite documentation.](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode)

Comment: Not helpful chatGPT.